# JDK 11 and oracle database (RDBMS) version 11.2.0.1 compatibility

Tags: java, ojdbc, oracle11gr2

Is it possible to upgrade the Java version (JDK) of the web application from 8 to 11 without upgrade my oracle database version (RDBMS) 11.2.0.1 to higher versions?
if it's possible which version of ojdbc driver is required?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are well.
If you need to upgrade the RDBMS, the upgrade process him self upgrade the user databases and in the software to use them, can be need change somthing like connector or driver, or pice of software between the Application Software (Client, Web, Service, etc.) and the RDBMS server. In general.

But if you need to upgrade your software (Client, Web, Service, etc.) for a new JDK/JVM, check if available the connector or driver for connect to the old RDBM. No need to upgrade the RDBMS.

Setup a test environment and check if the new JDK/JVM can connect with the current RDBMS. Create a simple java project, and make a lot of stress test and verify the stability of the connection.
Also and last, check documentation, find information in web and don't cut steps, because the productivity of the entire system is in yours hands.

I did this work for a .NET Solution and I change the version of compilations of Projects, using MySQL without upgrade, and everithing done well.